# How do I extract words in documents (.docx) and transform it into csv for clustering?

Tags: python, csv, cluster-analysis, k-means, docx

I'm new in python but i would like to try to do clustering using k-means. but first i need to extract my documents so i can execute preprocessing process. after that i'd like to transform it into csv. Can anyone suggest what step do I need to take?

Answer (score 0):

A good start would be to figure out how to extract the words from a document. A quick search yielded this [library](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

If you are looking to do this part without a library, here's an [article](http://etienned.github.io/posts/extract-text-from-word-docx-simply/) that provides a code snippet to read a .docx file using just the standard library

Answer (score 0):

You can strat around NLTK python library for the whole process